# Merging two pandas dataframes by interval

Tags: python, pandas, merge, time-series

I have two pandas dataframes with following format:

```
df_ts = pd.DataFrame([
        [10, 20, 1,  'id1'],
        [11, 22, 5,  'id1'],
        [20, 54, 5,  'id2'],
        [22, 53, 7,  'id2'],
        [15, 24, 8,  'id1'],
        [16, 25, 10, 'id1']
    ], columns = ['x', 'y', 'ts', 'id'])


df_statechange = pd.DataFrame([
        ['id1', 2, 'ok'],
        ['id2', 4, 'not ok'],
        ['id1', 9, 'not ok']
    ], columns = ['id', 'ts', 'state'])
```

I am trying to get it to the format, such as:

```
df_out = pd.DataFrame([
        [10, 20, 1,  'id1', None    ],
        [11, 22, 5,  'id1', 'ok'    ],
        [20, 54, 5,  'id2', 'not ok'],
        [22, 53, 7,  'id2', 'not ok'],
        [15, 24, 8,  'id1', 'ok'    ],
        [16, 25, 10, 'id1', 'not ok']
    ], columns = ['x', 'y', 'ts', 'id', 'state'])
```

I understand how to accomplish it iteratively by grouping by id and then iterating through each row and changing status when it appears. Is there a pandas build-in more scalable way of doing this?

Comment: I cant figure out the relating between `df_statechange` and `df_ts` to `df_out`, could you explain a little bit more

Comment: I think you also need `cut` aside from `merge`. See this thread for more details http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42649224/pandas-alternate-way-to-add-new-column-with-lot-of-conditions-other-than-apply

Comment: I believe you would have to create a function to join the frames as you desire. Basically take a row of the data frame and compare it over the rows of the other dataframe. apply the function over the first dataframe.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately pandas merge support only equality joins. See more details at the following thread:
[merge pandas dataframes where one value is between two others](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30627968/merge-pandas-dataframes-where-one-value-is-between-two-others)
if you want to merge by interval you'll need to overcome the issue, for example by adding another filter after the merge:

```
joined = a.merge(b,on='id')
joined = joined[joined.ts.between(joined.ts1,joined.ts2)]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can merge pandas data frames on two columns:

```
pd.merge(df_ts,df_statechange, how='left',on=['id','ts'])
```

in `df_statechange` that you shared here there is no common values on ts in both dataframes. Apparently you just copied not complete data frame here. So i got this output:

```
    x   y  ts   id state
0  10  20   1  id1   NaN
1  11  22   5  id1   NaN
2  20  54   5  id2   NaN
3  22  53   7  id2   NaN
4  15  24   8  id1   NaN
5  16  25  10  id1   NaN
```

But indeed if you have common `ts` in the data frames it will have your desired output. For example:

```
df_statechange = pd.DataFrame([
        ['id1', 5, 'ok'],
        ['id1', 8, 'ok'],
        ['id2', 5, 'not ok'],
        ['id2',7, 'not ok'],
        ['id1', 9, 'not ok']
    ], columns = ['id', 'ts', 'state'])
```

the output:

```
  x   y  ts   id   state
0  10  20   1  id1     NaN
1  11  22   5  id1      ok
2  20  54   5  id2  not ok
3  22  53   7  id2  not ok
4  15  24   8  id1      ok
5  16  25  10  id1     NaN
```

Comment: I am trying to merge dataframes on intervals, so often there are no common values. Basically idea behind df_statechange is that it carries over state of this id for all timestamps in df_ts, until this state is changed.