# Is there a way to sum values that if/fall in a specific interval bin?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have data in two different data frames:

First data frame, where `binned` is a `pd.Interval`:

```py
    zip     binned                  bin_count
0   07302   (325000.0, 662500.0]    6
1   07302   (662500.0, 1000000.0]   14
2   07302   (1000000.0, 1337500.0]  2
3   07302   (1337500.0, 1675000.0]  3
4   07302   (1675000.0, 2012500.0]  3
5   07302   (2012500.0, 2350000.0]  2
```

Second data frame:

```py
    zip     listing_close_price price_interest
0   07302   730000.0            0.047237
1   07302   1650000.0           1.000000
2   07302   509000.0            0.032936
3   07302   685000.0            0.044325
4   07302   660000.0            1.000000
```

Such that my first data frame will have an extra column, because in my second data frame rows `0` and `1` both fall in first data frame index `0`  = `.07`.

Final data frame:

```py
    zip     binned                  bin_count total_price_interest
0   07302   (325000.0, 662500.0]    6         .07
1   07302   (662500.0, 1000000.0]   14
2   07302   (1000000.0, 1337500.0]  2
3   07302   (1337500.0, 1675000.0]  3         .1
4   07302   (1675000.0, 2012500.0]  3
5   07302   (2012500.0, 2350000.0]  2
```

Thanks in advance!

Unfortunately, I've been going in circles and am unclear about where to start.

Comment: It would be simpler if you split the bin values into separate `bin_start` and `bin_end` columns.

Comment: Thanks what makes it easier with that approach? I'm still able to check values in a pd.Interval with a `in` statement

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that it was an interval value, thought it was a tuple.

Comment: Anyway, use the `in` check in a `join` condition.

Comment: Thanks, @Barmar. It's the join part where I'm getting hung up on as the df are not the same length.  Do you have a example of how it would look? As I would need to perform a sum operation as well.

Comment: This may be helpful: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44106304/merging-two-pandas-dataframes-by-interval

Comment: Thank you so much @Barmar your idea and the link helped a lot. Thanks again!